# How to Remove a Column from a huge html table using any Text Editor

Tags: html, html-table, text-editor, tablecolumn

I have an html table which contains 25,000 rows and 8 columns I want to remove 1st, 2nd, 7th and 8th columns from the table, I can use some Design tools such as MS Visual web developer and Dreamweaver but it take too much time to render the table and some time it does not respond, I am looking for some text editor where I can get the same functionality to increase the performance.

Comment: You can use vim to record a macro when you remove the mentioned columns for the first row, and then play it back 24,999 times. It would take some time to complete though, but you can let it run.

Comment: You could use Microsoft Excel (not sure of any free alternatives) and just remove each column as required.

Comment: can you import html tables into excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple code on javascript.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     if(j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 6 || j == 7) {
        row.removeChild(col)
     }
   }  
}
```

here is [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/unh6adyc/)

Comment: That's clever. You only have to copy the modified html table afterwards. Nice